# Laravel Unable to connect to database using Docker Compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a Laravel application trying to Docker as the development environment. I am using Docker Compose to orchestrate the docker. I am now having trouble in connecting to database. Here is what I have done so far.

I have created a `docker-compose.yml` in the project root folder.

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: easy_eat_apache
        image: webdevops/apache:ubuntu-16.04
        environment:
            WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
            WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN: easy-eat.localhost
            WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
        volumes: # Only shared dirs to apache (to be served)
        - ./public:/var/www/public:cached
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:cached
        networks:
        - easy-eat-network
        ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    php-fpm:
        container_name: easy_eat_php
        image: jguyomard/laravel-php:7.2
        volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/
        - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
        - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
        - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
        - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
        - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
        networks:
        - easy-eat-network
    db:
        container_name: easy_eat_db
        image: mariadb:10.2
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: easy_eat
            MYSQL_USER: easy_eat
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
        - easy-eat-network
        ports:
        - "33060:3306"
networks:
    easy-eat-network:
        driver: "bridge"
volumes:
    db_data:
        driver: "local"
```

Then I run the following command to spin up the environment.

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

I modified the database credentials in the env file like this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=easy_eat
DB_USERNAME=easy_eat
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

To ensure that my laravel application can connect to the database, I run the migration command as follow.

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

I got the following error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'easy_eat'@'172.25.0.4' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'easy_eat'@'172.25.0.4' (using password: YES)")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=easy_eat", "easy_eat", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

What is wrong with setting and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There is already a project using Docker previously. In the docker-compose file, db container is using the db_data volume. So it is causing conflict with the existing project. So, I had to changed my configuration to as follow.

[image]